# Howto create a bootable pendrive for windows manually on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, usb, boot, usb-flash-drive

I've been trying around but am not through yet. Where is my procedure failing? I have a 2G usb disk which I prepare the following way:

```
1 - Make a partition with fdisk yielding /dev/sdb1
2 - mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1
3 - parted /dev/sdb and set partition one bootable with: set 1 boot on
4 - copy iso content onto pendrive: dd if=winxpproinstallationdisk.img of=/dev/sdb1 bs=100M
5 - make MBR: install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sdb which means: 

    n      Never display the prompt (unless an error occurs).
    D      The partition marked with the bootable flag in the partition table.
    0      Timeout zero.
```

unplug. Boot on target machine which has USB booting enabled in its BIOS:

```
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://jaxov.com/2009/09/install-windows-7-from-usb-stick-easily-unetbootin/ it should be possible to install Windows installation disks onto  a USB-Stick using unetbootin (I know this article is for windows 7, but it should work for XP, too). **Unetbootin** (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) can be found in the repositories of most GNU/Linux distributions.

About what you were trying to do: It doesn't make sense to first create a filesystem on /dev/sdb1 and then overwrite it with the ISO image. This should work fine by just doing the following:

- `dd if=winxpproinstallationdisk.img of=/dev/sdb`

Don't mess with the MBR after that and note that this command isn't writing to the partition /dev/sdb1 but to the drive as a whole.

If this doesn't work, you could try out Multisystem (http://liveusb.info/dotclear/). The site is french, but I once succesfully downloaded it, so it should be possible. Here's an english site about it: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/

Comment: unetbootin didn't work for me. I installed it on my debian but it threw two errors while copying the iso to the pendrive.

Comment: Then try the second method I described.

Comment: That didn't work either, but let me try it once again

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't boot the ISO, i see just a blinking prompt.

Comment: Try multisystem (as in my edit of the answer, otherwise I can't help you, the only idea I have left if this doesn't work is to install windows on a virtual machine and create the LiveUSB-Stick from there)

Comment: FWIF, I've never had any luck creating a windows boot USB with UnetBootin. Linux variants (Clonezilla, Ubuntu, etc) always work a treat though.

Comment: With unetbootin it says "BOOTMGR is missing. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart" ... so maybe I will try to install the MBR as given above? After above install-mbr ... it says additionally to the missing line above the line: MBR and than a blank line.

Comment: With installing multisystem I had no luck yet

Comment: For multisystem ubuntu is needed, I have an old debian squeeze running.